# Try catch throw won't work for a wrong string

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I am learning try-catch error handling in javascript. Just for practice, I declared a string using incorrect syntax and tried to figure out the error using try-catch. But this time, no error was thrown by javascript.

```js
<script>
    try{
      document.write=("Incorrect syntax");
        }catch(obj){
          document.write(obj.message + "<br/>");
      }
    document.write("Correct String");

<script/>
```

The same thing happens with this also :

```js
<script>
    try{
      document.write"Incorrect syntax");
        }catch(obj){
          document.write(obj.message);
      }
    document.write("Correct String");

<script>
```

I want to know if I have made a mistake or this is not the correct practice for identifying these types of errors.

Comment: Syntax errors are triggered at parsing time, `try .. catch` catches runtime errors only. So, you haven't made any mistake, and this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try-Catch Blocks

**Try-catch blocks** are  made so that your program doesn't suddenly crash in case of a **run-time error**. They are not for catching syntax error. But they can only catch errors that occur while runtime.

You cannot use try-catch blocks to handle syntax errors as they are thrown while the **code is being parsed and not while it's running**.

You can **catch programmer-generated and runtime exceptions** with try-catch block of error handling, but you cannot catch JavaScript syntax errors.

---

Now you may be wondering, if Javascript can't catch syntax errors, then why is the **SyntaxError** an error type that can be caught in try-catch block?

- In Javascript, SyntaxError are errors that will be thrown during runtime, not during compile-time.
- For eg. `JSON.parse()` parses a string as JSON. This string has to be valid JSON and will throw this error if **incorrect syntax** was encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Try-catch block only catches run-time exceptions not javascript syntax errors.